# AutoMapper on complicated Views (multiple looping)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, automapper

Earlier today, a helpful person (here on Stack Overflow) pointed me towards [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), I checked it out, and I liked it a lot! Now however I am a little stuck.

In my Code First MVC3 Application, on my [Home/Index] I need to display the following information from my Entities:

1. List of Posts [ int Id, string Body, int Likes, string p.User.FirstName, string p.User.LastName ]
2. List of Tags [int Id, string Name]
3. List of All Authors that exist on my Database [ string UrlFriendlyName ]

So far I have managed only point 1 in the list by doing the following for my Index ViewModel:

```
public class IndexVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
}
```

And on the Home Controller, Index ActionMethod I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Posts = postsRepository.Posts.ToList();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Post, IndexVM>();
    var IndexModel = Mapper.Map<List<Post>, List<IndexVM>>(Posts);
    return View(IndexModel);
}
```

Finally on my View I have it strongly typed to:

```
@model IEnumerable<BlogWeb.ViewModels.IndexVM>
```

And I am passing each Item in the IndexVM IEnumberable to a Partial View via:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_PostDetails", item)
}
```

My question is, how can I also achieve point 2 and 3, whilst not breaking what I've achieved in point 1.

I tried putting the stuff I currently have for IndexVM into a SubClass, and having a List Property on the Parent class, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to including all of your lists of entities on a single viewmodel, you could use @Html.Action. Then, in your screen view:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Posts")
@Html.Action("Index", "Tags")
@Html.Action("Index", "Authors")
```

This way, your Index / Screen view & model don't need to know about the other viewmodels. The partials are delivered by separate child action methods on separate controllers.

All of the automapper stuff still applies, but you would still map your entities to viewmodels individually. The difference is, instead of doing the mapping in HomeController.Index(), you would do it in PostsController.Index(), TagsController.Index(), and AuthorsController.Index().

**Response to comment 1**

```
public class IndexVM
{
    // need not implement anything for Posts, Tags, or Authors
}
```

Then, implement 3 different methods on 3 different controllers. Here is one example for the PostsController. Follow the same pattern for TagsController and AuthorsController

```
// on PostsController
public PartialViewResult Index()
{
    var posts = postsRepository.Posts.ToList();

    // as mentioned, should do this in bootstrapper, not action method
    Mapper.CreateMap<Post, PostModel>();

    // automapper2 doesn't need source type in generic args
    var postModels = Mapper.Map<List<PostModel>>(posts); 
    return PartialView(postModels);
}
```

You will have to create a corresponding partial view for this, strongly-typed as `@model IEnumerable<BlogWeb.ViewModels.PostModel>`. In that view, put the HTML that renders the Posts UI (move from your HomeController.Index view).

On your HomeController, just do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new IndexVM);
}
```

Keep your view strongly-typed on the IndexVM

```
@model IEnumerable<BlogWeb.ViewModels.IndexVM>
```

... and then get the Posts, Tags, and Authors like so:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Posts")
```

**Response to comment 2**

Bootstrapping... your Mapper.CreateMap configurations only have to happen once per app domain. This means you should do all of your CreateMap calls from Application_Start. Putting them in the controller code just creates unnecessary overhead. Sure, the maps need to be created - but not during each request.

This also helps with unit testing. If you put all of your Mapper.CreateMap calls into a single static method, you can call that method from a unit test method as well as from Global.asax Application_Start. Then in the unit test, one method can test that your CreateMap calls are set up correctly:

```
AutoMapperBootStrapper.CreateAllMaps();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: Thank You OliveHour. I get it now. It sort of creates like Widgets, where you can place anywhere you want to. And that is quite good for me, cause Tags and Users are sort of Widgets in the Sidebar. Thank You So much. I still don't understand the big about Bootstrapping .. can you briefly explain that and why it is needed? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

From the ASP.NET MVC2 In Action Book:

> Some screens are more complex than a single table. They may feature
>   multiple tables and additional fields of other data: images, headings,
>   subtotals, graphs, charts, and a million other things that complicate
>   a view. The presentation model solution scales to handle them all.
>   Developers can confidently maintain even the gnarliest screens as long
>   as the presentation model is designed well. If a screen does contain
>   multiple complex elements, a presentation model can be a wrapper,
>   composing them all and relieving the markup file of much complexity. A
>   good presentation model doesn’t hide this complexity—it represents it
>   accurately and as simply as possible, and it separates the data on a
>   screen from the display.

Make a ViewModel that represents your screen.  Then build it up and pass it to the View.  [This](http://www.manning.com/palermo2/) book is great and talks about using a presentation model.  With AutoMapper, think about how you would accomplish your mapping without it, then make use of it.  AutoMapper isn't going to do anything magic, it eliminates keyboard slapping.

AutoMapper aside, take your list of requirments:

1. List of Posts [ int Id, string Body, int Likes, string p.User.FirstName, string p.User.LastName ]
2. List of Tags [int Id, string Name]
3. List of All Authors that exist on my Database [ string
   UrlFriendlyName ]

and assuming you have these Model entites: Post, Tag, Author

Personally I don't like passing Model entities to my presentation in MVC or MVVM but that's me.  Say we follow that here and create PostDisplay, TagDisplay, and AuthorDisplay.

Based on the View's requirements the ViewModel will look like this:

```
Public class IndexVM
{
    Public List<PostDisplay> Posts {get; set;}
    Public List<TagDisplay> Tags {get; set;}
    Public List<AuthorDisplay> Authors {get; set;}
}
```

In this case the way the View is composed will require you to build it up:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var posts = postsRepository.Posts.ToList();
    var tags = postsRepository.Tags.ToList();
    var authors = postsRepository.Authors.ToList();

    Mapper.CreateMap<Post, PostDisplay>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, TagDisplay>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Author, AuthorDisplay>();

    private var IndexVM = new IndexVM
    {
        Posts = Mapper.Map<List<Post>, List<PostDisplay>>(posts),
        Tags = Mapper.Map<List<Tag>, List<TagDisplay>>(tags),
        Authors = Mapper.Map<List<Author>, List<AuthorDisplay>>(authors)
    };

    return View(IndexVM);
}
```

So, what you end up with is a ViewModel to pass to your view that represents exactly what you want to display and isn't tightly coupled to your Domain Model.  I can't think of a way to have AutoMapper map three separate result lists into one object.

To clarify, AutoMapper will map child collections so a structure like:

```
public class OrderItemDto{}
public class OrderDto
{
    public List<OrderItemDto> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

will map to:

```
public class OrderItem{}
public class Order
{
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

As long as you tell it how to map the types: OrderDto -> Order and OrderItemDto -> OrderItem.

Comment: *Thank You* for the reply Derek. I have gone ahead and done as you suggested ([PasteBin Here](http://pastebin.com/wwddHQDx)). But I have no clue how to proceed with the AutoMapper now. How do I tell the AutoMapper to do its thing with the way my ViewModel is now ? Thanks

Comment: Updated, also check out http://www.manning.com/palermo2/ this book has  a nice chapter on presentation models.

Comment: Just so you know I accidentally downvoted instead of upvoting. Now the downvote is locked without an edit. If you make an edit I will change the vote to an upvote

Comment: Still not working I'm afraid :( I'm getting a [AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException] on the first line of the [following code](http://pastebin.com/AXzh10Xa). Don't we have to do [ Mapper.CreateMap ] before doing the Mapper.Map ? That's what the video showed at least, but still don't know how to configure it though. ;'(

Comment: Yeah, you only need to create the maps once.  You can do that in a Bootstrapper of some sort or by using profiles.  Bootstrapper http://goo.gl/B58n9 called from http://goo.gl/zBwyp

Comment: **Thank You** So Much Derek, **It worked !**. You've been a great help. Can you elaborate on the BootStrap thinggy .. what does it do ? and why do I need it ? Thanks

Comment: It's just a a place to stick startup configuration stuff like setting up maps.  It could be called AutoMapperConfig.cs.